# Laravel custom controller not found when changing the controller directory

Tags: laravel-controller

When changing the controller directory location like so:

```
Route::group([
  'prefix'      => 'report',
  'middleware'  => 'auth',
], function() {
    Route::get('/summary','IOS\ReportController@index');
});
```

It returns an error message:

```
Error
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\IOS\Controller' not found
```

But it's working perfectly the below way:

```
Route::group([
  'prefix'      => 'report',
  'middleware'  => 'auth',
], function() {
    Route::get('/summary','ReportController@index');
});
```

After changing directory location, i try to `composer dump-autoload` but it's still getting error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

every `Controller` on laravel should `extends` the base laravel `Controller`
the base controller is in this path: `App\Http\Controllers`
so when you create a controller on another folder, the created controller wants to extend from the base controller but can not find it in folder
so you should do this on `ReportController`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\IOS;   //namespace of your controller
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;  //the path of base Controller

class ReportController extends Controller  //your controller extends from base controller
```